ANTLR 4 - Error: invalid escape sequence \" when processing Java.g4 grammar file
I am learning ANTLR 4 using the book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference". In Chapter 4, "A Quick Tour", on page 44, I downloaded the tour/Java.g4 file (http://media.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/code/tour/Java.g4) and executed the command
antlr4 Java.g4

However, I encountered the following error:
error(156): Java.g4:653:35: invalid escape sequence \\"

Can someone explain why this error occurs and how to resolve it?
I executed the command
antlr4 Java.g4


Line 653:     :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')

The double quote should not be escaped. It's not '\"' but '"'. I believe some older v4 versions used to allow the escaping of characters that needn't be escaped, but has since been changed.
